# Find a function in terms of another

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, integral-transforms, boundary-value-problem

I need to express an in terms of f(x). I did it but I'm not sure if it is right.

> Consider 
>   \begin{cases}
> -u_{xx}+u=f(x), &0<x<\ell\\[0.5em]
> u_x(0)=0,\;u_x(l)=0&
> \end{cases}
>   Suppose that [a solution can be expressed as] $u(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,\cos\left(\frac{n\pi\,x}{\ell}\right)$. Find $a_n$ in terms of $f$.

[image]

Comment: Your task is to express $f$ as a Fourier series and then compare term by term for each frequency and phase. -- Please avoid large pictures, use the LaTeX/MathJax facilities of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last equation is wrong, the sums cover all terms containing $n$, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\left(\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ell}\right)^2+1\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi\,x}{\ell}\right)=f(x)
$$
Use that the functions $\cos\left(\frac{n\pi\,x}{\ell}\right)$ form an orthogonal sequence over the interval $(0,\ell)$. Or more directly, find the representation of $f$ as a cosine series.

Comment: Thanks! I figure out that my result was wrong. But what do you mean by express cos in the orthogonal form?